# Cargar valores en select desplegable con MySQL PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Dispongo de una tabla en mi base de datos llamada "tiposclientes", con 3 campos: idusuario, tipo, descuento.

Código de la clase **Tiposclientes**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Clase TiposClientes.
 */
class TiposClientes {
    private $idusuario;
    private $tipo;
    private $descuento;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase TiposClientes.
     * @param type $row
     */
    public function __construct($row){
        $this->idusuario = $row["idusuario"];
        $this->tipo = $row["tipo"];
        $this->descuento = $row["descuento"];
    }

    function getIdusuario() {
        return $this->idusuario;
    }

    function getTipo() {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    function getDescuento() {
        return $this->descuento;
    }

    function setIdusuario($idusuario) {
        $this->idusuario = $idusuario;
    }

    function setTipo($tipo) {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;
    }

    function setDescuento($descuento) {
        $this->descuento = $descuento;
    }


    function mostrarTiposClientes(){
        echo $this->idusuario;
        echo $this->tipo;
        echo $this->descuento;
    }
}
```

En un archivo .php realizo las consultas que deseo en este caso quiero **extraer todos los TIPO de tiposclientes**.

```
static public function obtenerTiposClientes(){
        //Realizamos la consulta.
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $registro = $ejecucion->query("SELECT * FROM tiposclientes;");
        return $registro;
    }
```

Y esos tipos quiero añadirlos en un combobox (menú desplegable), **¿por qué no me los carga en el select?**

**Código HTML + PHP para cargar los "tipo" en el select:**

```
<label>Tipos: <select name = "tipo">
                    <?php
                    $datos = BD::obtenerTiposClientes();
                    foreach($datos as $x){
                        echo "<option value='".$x['tipo']."'>".$x['tipo']."</option>";
                    }
                    ?> 
                </select>
                </label>
```

Comment: Todo parece estar bien. ¿Podrías añadir el código generado?

Comment: ¿A qué código generado te refieres? <label>Tipos: <select name = "tipo">
                    <?php
                    $datos = BD::obtenerTiposClientes();
                    foreach($datos as $x){
                        echo "<option value='".$x['tipo']."'>".$x['tipo']."</option>";
                    }
                    ?> 
                </select>
                </label>

Comment: Eso es código PHP como el de la pregunta. El código PHP genera el código HTML que es el que el navegador interpreta. Dale a “ver código fuente” en tu página y comparte el código HTML generado y no solo el PHP que lo genera.

Comment: Mira la captura de pantalla que voy a editar ahora mismo. Me salen todos los datos pero no me "rescata" solamente los tipos, (normal, premium, tarjeta oro).

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "_me salen todos los datos_"? Viendo el error que te da, parece que puede haber un problema de conexión a la base de datos o a la hora de recibir los datos (porque $datos seguramente es null), por lo que no te están saliendo los datos. ¿Cómo verificas que los datos los recibes bien?

Comment: Los datos los recibo bien debido a que en el método "mostrarTiposClientes()" me salen correctamente, anidados sin espacios y poco vistosos pero sí me aparecen correctamente. 1NORMAL02PREMIUM103TARJETA ORO30 (fíjate en la imagen).

Comment: El método *obtenerTiposClientes* no devuelve nada, solo muestra el echo por pantalla del método *mostrarTiposClientes*

Primero, deberias hacer que devolviera el array que esperas, y después tratarlo con el foreach

Comment: He añadido el return pero tampoco me soluciona el problema. Creo que el foreach lo tengo bien realizado, ¿no?

Comment: Todo solucionado. Era mucho más fácil que todo lo que quería hacer en el método obtenerTiposClientes, Eleazan dio con la clave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné de una manera más simple todavía, el problema estaba que recorría el foreach sin tener valores y no podía conseguir las columnas que deseaba. Me explico con el método clave:

```
static public function obtenerTiposClientes(){
   //Realizamos la consulta.
   $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
   $registro = $ejecucion->query("SELECT * FROM tiposclientes;");
   return $registro;
}
```

En esta consulta recojo TODA la información de la tabla, y la guardo en la variable $registros, a continuación a la otra de tratar los valores con el "foreach" solamente selecciono los que tengan el parámetro "tipo".

```
include "Clases/BD.php";
$datos = BD::obtenerTiposClientes();
foreach($datos as $x){
   echo "<option value=\'".$x['tipo']."\'>".$x['tipo']."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error grave en el echo donde estás imprimiendo los `<option>`, debería de ser de esta forma:

```
echo "<option value='".$x['tipo']."'>".$x['tipo']."</option>";
```

Comment: Cierto, pero aún así no me los muestra.

Comment: Y ya verificaste que si te estén llegando datos en $datos ?

Comment: Si me llegan ya hice un pequeño programa de prueba en "pruebas.php" que me muestre los datos y sí llegan. Código en pruebas.php es el siguiente: BD::obtenerTiposClientes();

Comment: @omaza1990 entonces si a tu foreach le estan llegando datos, y ya tienes la estructura de los option bien me acabas de corchar, todo parece estar bien

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu problema está en el foreach como dice el error. Puede ser por la forma en que muestras los `options`.

Prueba imprimir los options de la siguiente forma:

```
echo '<option value=\"'.$x[\"tipo\"].'\">'.$x[\"tipo\"].'</option>';
```

O si así no te funciona entonces pruebalo de esta otra forma:

```
echo "<option value=\'".$x['tipo']."\'>".$x['tipo']."</option>";
```

Espero te sirva, un saludo!

Comment: Esto no arregla mi problema, el problema está en que devuelve datos pero a la hora de tratarlos con el foreach no los trata bien parece ser. Ese es el problema... el "echo" está correcto.

Comment: Ya está arreglado. El error estaba en que NO retornada los valores, solo los estaba mostrando con un echo pero no los cogia para tratarlos con el FOREACH.

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas arreglado!. Sería interesante que pusieras tu solución en una respuesta, para que todos podamos ver por fin como lo solucionaste y así no se quede la pregunta sin solución y le sirva a otros. Saludos.